# Appointment Letter

Tags: visas, applications

I booked my appointment on 10th of June for UK visa at Vfs global site, I have paid GBP 53.00 for my appointment but I have not received any appointment letter, Can anyone guide me how to get an appointment letter. Will I be receiving any cofirmatory email ? I applied on Friday in the late evening hours. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Log in in following page

https://myappointment.vfsglobal.co.uk/MyAppointment

Download the application

Comment: when I login to my account it starts all over again. The appointment form starts from the very beginning just like the first time you login for making an appointment and is asking to fill the form. It doesn't show my already filled appointment form. I have paid for my appointment but I don't have an appointment letter. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot what you are seeing and post here..